# Will my neutered male hurt my female cats kittens?

Tags: cats, safety, multi-pet-families, breeding

My female cat is pregnant; I also own a neutered male cat. My question is: will the kittens be safe around him or should I keep him away from them?

Comment: Male cat is 3 yo and not the dad of the kittens

Comment: Parentage or not won’t matter with cats, as they don’t bond for a certain time frame and a (feral) female will copulate with multiple toms when in heat.